# c# Doing scan tcp ports without Out of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, tcp, ip, port, task

So I'm trying to scan open ports with a given IP-Adress.
I found some examples but I get an Out of Memory exception if I give 65535 tasks.
I though hmm, maybe it's to much. So I tried 2000.. Still to much. A 1000? YES.

But apperantly the problem lies at 'TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning'. If i try TaskCreationOptions.None is does everyhting but really slow!! like my grandma can scan ports much faster.

And the funny thing is, If I debug(F5 - Visual studio), then it works but if I execute the program without debugging it doesn't.
So I can scan 1000 ports in a few seconds, but how do I implement a queue?

Here is my code.
I tried looping, execute on finish, etc.. nothing :(

Any help is appriciated, Thanks in advance!

```
    private void ScanPorts()
    {
        int startPort = 1000;
        int endPoint = 65535;

        myProgressBar.Value = 0;
        myProgressBar.Step = 1;
        myProgressBar.Maximum = endPoint - startPort + 1;

        var scans = from i in Enumerable.Range(startPort, endPoint - startPort + 1)
                    select ScanSinglePortTask(i).ContinueWith(t => Response(t.Result), TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

        var tasks = scans.ToArray();

    }

    private Task<string> ScanSinglePortTask(int currPort)
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var tcpportScan = new TcpClient())
                {
                    tcpportScan.SendTimeout = 10;

                    tcpportScan.Connect("127.0.0.1", (int)currPort);
                }
                return "IP: 127.0.0.1 - Port " + currPort + " open.\n";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return "IP: 127.0.0.1 - Port " + currPort + " closed.\n";
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
    private void Response(object message)
    {
        lblProgress.Text = ((string)message);
        listBox1.Items.Add(((string)message));
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;
        myProgressBar.PerformStep();
    }
```

**EDIT**

***TEMP SOLUTION***

So I managed to get rid of the Out of Memory exception by setting my platform target from x86 to x64.

So apperantly a x86 has 2Gigs of VIRTUAL memory while x64 over 6TB+ VIRTUAL memory.

This isn't a solution if you ask me, but a temporary one.

***NEW SOLUTION***

x86 and x64 bit compatible!

A queueing system I implemented, no answers on this post so I thought I will share my solution for those who need it.

So basicly this code scans all ports of any given IP adress (1000 ports at the same time, so 1000 threads)
I can scan a local ip in 2 minutes, an internet IP a bit longer, maybe 5. Depending on your cpu speed  and internetconnection ofcourse.

I added some comments for you guys :)

(Please do no use this for hacking purposes xD **and Vote if you like this**)

```
public partial class PortScanner : Form
{
    private int totalScans = 0;
    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    public PortScanner()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //Check for valid IP
            if (IPAddress.TryParse(txtIP.Text, out ipAddress))
            {
                btnScan.Enabled = false;
                btnScan.Text = "Scanning...";

                //Stops GUI Freeze
                MethodInvoker startScanning = new MethodInvoker(ScanPorts);
                startScanning.BeginInvoke(null, null);

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ScanPorts()
    {
        int startPort = 1;
        int endPoint = 65535;

        // n ports to scan!
        int maxTheads = 1000;

        //Set progressbar 
        myProgressBar.Value = 0;
        myProgressBar.Step = 1;
        myProgressBar.Maximum = endPoint - startPort + 1;

        //Main task list (consist of multiple lists of 1000 tasks)
        List<List<Task>> myTasks = new List<List<Task>>();
        for (int i = startPort; i <= endPoint; i = i + maxTheads)
        {
            List<Task> subTasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int j = i; j < i + maxTheads && j <= endPoint; j++)
            {
                subTasks.Add(ScanSinglePortTask(j));
            }
            myTasks.Add(subTasks);
        }

        //Start ALL TASKS
        startTask(myTasks);

    }
    public void startTask(List<List<Task>> myTasks)
    {
        //A thousand task at a time.
        foreach (List<Task> t in myTasks)
        {
            foreach (Task st in t)
            {
                st.Start();
            }
            Task.WaitAll(t.ToArray());
        }
        btnScan.Enabled = true;
        btnScan.Text = "Start Scanning";
    }

    private Task ScanSinglePortTask(int currPort)
    {
        return new Task(()=>
        {
            try
            {
                using (var tcpportScan = new TcpClient())
                {
                    tcpportScan.SendTimeout = 10;
                    tcpportScan.Connect(ipAddress, (int)currPort);

                }
                Response("IP: " + ipAddress.ToString() + " - Port " + currPort + " open.\n");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Response("IP: " + ipAddress.ToString() + " - Port " + currPort + " closed.\n");
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
    private void Response(object message)
    {
        totalScans++;
        if (message != null)
        {
            try
            {
                lblProgress.Text = "Total portscan: " + totalScans.ToString();
                lbConnections.Items.Add(((string)message));
                lbConnections.SelectedIndex = lbConnections.Items.Count - 1;
                myProgressBar.PerformStep();
                if (((string)message).EndsWith("open.\n"))
                {
                    lbOpenConnections.Items.Add((string)message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each managed thread or fibre in .Net consumes a megabyte of stack space. If you don't need that much stack space and would like to have more threads (not saying this is a good idea, by the way!) you can control the stack space size, reducing it should allow more threads to be created

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/rickm/archive/2008/04/22/increasing-the-size-of-your-stack-net-memory-management-part-3.aspx

This article will help you understand why LongRunning is having an impact; you're basically bypassing the threadpool and creating a dedicated thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963549.aspx

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Allan Elder Thanks for the response, yet can't seem to figure this out man. Maybe a queueing solution?